# React NavLink active classname on detail page

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am using `NavLink` on *navbar*, so I can use `activeClassName` property and it can add active class on my *navbar*. But my problem is when I enter a detail page, I can't see active class anymore. Let me show you with some photos for better understanding.

Normal Page :

[image]

When, I click a service from cards its going to detail page.

[image]

**What I want :** When I click a detail card Services part should be active still. What can I do about that ?

My *Navbar*: (I am making that *navbar* from an array that's why it have `x`. X is my 1 element.)

```
<NavLink
  activeClassName="active-nav"
  exact
  key={x.key}
  className="   text-white truncate  flex self-center items-center lg:px-5 xl:px-6 2xl:px-10  "
  style={{ fontSize: "17px", lineHeight: "28px" }}
  to={x.Link}
  >
    {x.Name}
</NavLink>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to remove `exact` from the `NavLink`

```
              <NavLink
                activeClassName="active-nav"
                key={x.key}
                className="   text-white truncate  flex self-center items-center lg:px-5 xl:px-6 2xl:px-10  "
                style={{ fontSize: "17px", lineHeight: "28px" }}
                to={x.Link}
              >
                {x.Name}
              </NavLink>
```

And then when you render the detail page, it should be rendered as the child of the `Service` Page. For example if `localhost:3000/treatments` is your service page url then the detail page should be `localhost:3000/treatments/detail?id=1`